# mysql statement with using the [charlist] Wildcard

Tags: mysql

Trying to use this sql statement. The first 2 parts work fine, I am trying in corporate charlist so that the string its pulling cannot contain any of the letters in it

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE LENGTH(RTRIM(word)) = 8 AND word LIKE 'a__c____' AND word LIKE '%[!tesp]%' GROUP BY word
```

Basically I want this statement to pull up a word that is:

- 8 letters in length
- starts with "a" and 4th letter is "c"
- does not contain "t" "e" "s" "p" in it

Comment: I think you have to use Regular expression for this refer http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/regexp.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`REGEXP`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/regexp.html) (or its synonym `RLIKE`) operator for this.

```
SELECT *
FROM table
WHERE word RLIKE '^a[^tesp]{2}c[^tesp]{4} *$'
GROUP BY word;
```

The `[^tesp]{2}` means "match 2 characters that are not t, e, s or p".

Note that the 8-letters is enforced by the regex. Also, it handles the `RTRIM` by the `*$` at the end of the regex (allowing any number of spaces at the end).

This lets you just do one pass over each word instead of three (once for `LENGTH`, once for `LIKE 'a__c____'` and once for the "t","e","s","p").

Comment: Dang that was one of the best answers I have ever gotten, not only did you solve my question, you shortened my sql statement on top of that :)

Answer (score 0):

This should be sufficient for the where clause to answer the problem as described:

```
word rlike '^a[a-z]{2}c[a-z]{4}$' and work not rlike '[tesp]'
```

although it could be collapsed into one regexp:

```
word rlike '^a[a-df-oqru-z]{2}c[a-df-oqru-z]{4}$'
```

I'd go with the two rlike form if I were you, for maintainibility for certain, and most likely for performance as well.

Comment: Note, above solution w/ [^tesp] doesn't eliminate "words" like 'a   c    '.